# php nested array returning undefined index

Tags: php, arrays

I can't seem to figure out why my code returns "undefined index "Account"

Below is my array data and code

Data:-

```
$file_array = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Account] => 123456789
        [Portfolio_id] => 111
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [Account] => 987654321
        [Portfolio_id] => 112
    )
)
```

code:-

```
foreach ($file_array as $k=>$data) {
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['Account']); //line 578
}
```

Error:-

```
Notice:  Undefined index: Account in app/controllers/DataController.php on line 578
```

If i `print_r($data['Portfolio_id'])`, the value is returned. I am only getting the error when trying to print `$data['Account']`

I can't seem to find the error in my code. Maybe someone here will be able to see it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If that's really the value of `$file_array`, I don't see the problem either.

Comment: @Barmar it is. If i print `$file_array`, it's shown the values just like that.

Comment: Maybe there's whitespace in the keys?

Comment: I checked for whitespaces. There isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix array

```
$file_array = array(
  array(
        'Account' => 123456789,
        'Portfolio_id' => 111
      ),
  array(
       'Account' => 987654321,
       'Portfolio_id' => 112
    )
);

foreach ($file_array as $k=>$data) {
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data['Account']); //line 578
}
```